# Git-Eclipse - How to get latest version from master branch

Tags: eclipse, git

In Eclipse Neon
How to replace local master branch with remote / origin without having outcoming / though void / differences in the synchronise view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [reset your current branch (`master`) to a specific branch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reset_to_specific_branch_or_tag) (`origin/master`)

> Select `Team -> Reset...` on a project. This opens a dialog where you can select a branch or a tag.

Chose (if you don't have any work in progress) the "hard" option (git reset --hard)